# Magento foreach() orders getAllItems()

Tags: magento, foreach

I am not sure why this loop is not working.

```
    $orders = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order')->getCollection()  
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')  
        ->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$from, 'to'=>$to)) 
        ->addAttributeToSort('increment_id', 'ASC')
        ;

    foreach ($orders as $item) { 
        $order_id = $item->increment_id;
        if (is_numeric($order_id)) $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order_id);
        if (is_object($order)) {
            echo "> O: ". $order_id ."<BR>";
            $items = $order->getAllItems();
            echo ">> O: ". $order_id ."<BR>";
        } else
            die("DIE ". var_dump($order));  
    }
die("<BR> DONE");
```

The output:

```
...
...
>> O: 100021819
> O: 100021820
>> O: 100021820
> O: 100021821
```

The loop never finishes nor does it stop at the same order_id.?

It always fails at $order->getAllItems()

These orders are either pending, processing or complete.

Is there something I should be checking for with $order->getAllItems(), since that's were it's failing.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried running the PHP script from command line?  Script that stops looping at random places that's usually indication of PHP timeout error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jon, I assume the problem you're talking about is your script ending un expectedly.  i.e., you see the output with a single `>`

```
> O: 100021821
```

but not the output with the double `>>`.

Because Magento is so customizable, it's impossible to accurately diagnose your problem with the information given.  Something is happening in your system, (a PHP error, an uncaught exception, etc.), that results in your script stopping.  Turn on developer mode and set the PHP ini `display_errors` to 1 (`ini_set('display_errors', 1);`) and check your error log.  One you (or we) have the PHP error, it'll be a lot easier to help you.

My guess is you're running into a memory problem.  The way PHP has implemented objects can lead to small memory leaks — objects don't clean up after themselves correctly. This means each time you go through the loop you're slowly consuming the total amount of memory that's allowed for a PHP request.  For a system with a significant number of orders, I'd be surprised if the above code could get through everything before running out of memory.

If your problem is a memory problem, there's information on manually cleaning up after PHP's objects [in this PDF](http://www.magentocommerce.com/images/uploads/PHP_Garbage_Collector_final2.pdf).  You should also consider splitting your actions into multiple requests.  i.e. The first request handles orders 1 - 100, the next 101 - 200, etc.

Comment: That was it, out of memory. ini_set('memory_limit','128M'); Works now, thank you.

Comment: did't I just say that? haha :-p

Comment: PHP does have garbage collection to free up memory, but it can't free up memory consumed by objects with circular references to themselves, which Magento has. Therefore it is Magento that has memory leaks, not PHP itself.

Comment: @JoshRibakoff You'd find an equal number of people who'd say this is the fault of a poor garbage collector implementation.

Comment: That's a valid argument, and I happen to agree, but the problem in Magento is patchable with userland code - see http://paul-m-jones.com/archives/262

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean it fails? 
By the look of the output it doesn't fail there as it outputs text either side of the call to getAllItems()

change:

```
$items = $order->getAllItems();
```

to:

```
foreach($order->getAllItems() as $orderItem) {
    echo $orderItem->getId() . "<br />";
}
```

and see what happens.

The script could be ending on a different order ID each time if you have a low memory limit set on the server and it quits when it runs out of resources.